# How to load multiple unrelated objects with RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, core-data, restkit

I need to load mulitple objects that don't have relationships but located on the same remote API using RestKit into CoreData (in other words download remote objects to use them locally in iOS)

So I've setup my Client and objectManager:

```
client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]]; 
[client setUsername:@"someUsername"];
[client setPassword:@"somePassword"];

objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:baseUrl];
[objectManager setClient:client];
```

Then I setup some mappings for one Object#1:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* companyMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Company" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
companyMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"backendID";
[companyMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"backendID"];
[companyMapping mapKeyPath:@"company_name" toAttribute:@"companyName"];
```

Then I setup some mappings for Object #2:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* eventMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Event" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
eventMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"backendID";
[eventMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"backendID"];
[eventMapping mapKeyPath:@"description" toAttribute:@"eventDescription"];
```

After that I set objectMapping to mappingProvider:

```
 [objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:companyMapping forResourcePathPattern:remoteObjectPath];
 [objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:eventMapping forResourcePathPattern:remoteObjectPath];
```

And lastly I call "loadObjects..." for both of these objects one after another:

```
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteCompaniesObjectPath delegate:self];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteEventsObjectPath delegate:self];
```

What happens after this that data from both Companies and Events is somehow loaded into the Events table, so table data is completely unusable.
If I run only `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteCompaniesObjectPath` then everything works as expected remote Company object downloads into it's own table in the CoreData.

While it does make sense why it's happening (data For Companies starting to load and gets new mapping, so it loads to the wrong table) the **QUESTION** is:
How to call `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteObjectPath` methods to load multiple unrelated objects so they would properly loaded into their respective tables in the CoreData???

Answer (score 0):

Well I think there is nothing There for restkit to distinguish between two object types company and events.

There are two ways of going about this. Both are straightforward, upto you what to choose:

1. You provide a rootkeypath to restkit for both company and events. And then you modify your api to include a rootkeypath in the json. Something like below..

   ["company":{
                "Backendid":1
                 "company name":"abc"
                }
       {"events":{
               {Backendid":1
                 "description":"party"
               }]

   In this case restkit will know which is an event and what is a company and will automatically map to the right table.. Checkout rkgithub example for more tips.
2. You set your online api to have 2 different urls for both. So then the different URL will be make sure restkit doesn't get tables mixed up.

Also something to ask here, does your events column have a company name column as well? Because I would have thought restkit will give you an error as from your mapping there doesn't seem to be a column named company name in an events table. Are you trying to do some sort of to-many relationship here? Where company has-many events type of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, however option#1 is not very good as I don't have much leverage on changing the API. Option #2 sounds better however both remote objects have different URLs already, please note: loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteCompaniesObjectPath and loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteEventsObjectPath. So path of companies something like: http://somedomain.com/api/companies... and path for events: http://somedomain.com/api/events..  I thought this is enough for Restkit to distinguish but it's not.

Comment: Also there is no relation between Event and Company object.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping provider needs a tweak -- set each mapping with its respective URL.

Change mapping from:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:companyMapping forResourcePathPattern:remoteObjectPath];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:eventMapping forResourcePathPattern:remoteObjectPath];
```

To:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:companyMapping forResourcePathPattern: remoteCompaniesObjectPath];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:eventMapping forResourcePathPattern:remoteEventsObjectPath];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in my case both of the "remoteObjectPath" are different strings setup right before calling the method. It's still not working as supposed to. Is it working for you?

Comment: " If I run only loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteCompaniesObjectPath then everything works as expected " Does it also work if you only loadObjectsAtResourcePath:remoteEventsObjectPath?

Comment: Yes, the scenario of multiple mappings for different resource paths using one mapping provider works for me. RKGitHub is a great reference for this question: https://github.com/RestKit/RKGithub